# phpspreadsheet mas de 20000 registros

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy realizando un aplicativo web de proyecto de grado  y no he podido resolver un problema. la cuestion es que necesito realizar una exportacion masiva de registros MYSQL  a una plantilla de excel  lo estoy realizando con phpspreadsheet en laravel 5.5

esta es una parte del codigo realizo un for para insertar ciertos registros  especificos,  cuando lo hago con  menos de 500 registros no hay porblema pero cuando ya inserto muchos mas  como es el caso de 20000. me aparece lo siguiente Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded y nose como podria resolverlo

```
 for ($i=0; $i <$tamanio; $i++) { 
            if($llamarBDValidados[$i]->indiceUser ==$indicadorUser){
        $hojaActual->getCell('A'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->Colilla);
        $hojaActual->getCell('B'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->Producto);
        $hojaActual->getCell('C'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->validado);
        $hojaActual->getCell('D'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->observacion);
        $hojaActual->getCell('E'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->NTrocado);
        $hojaActual->getCell('F'.$cont)->setValue($llamarBDValidados[$i]->indiceUser);
        $hojaActual->getCell('G'.$cont)->setValue(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($llamarBDValidados[$i]->created_at)->format('d/m/Y'));
        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($documento, 'Xls'); 
          $writer->save("reporte.xls");
          $cont++;
```

Comment: lo siento y gracias por la redaccion

Comment: ¿Ya mediste en dónde se consume la mayor parte del tiempo? si en la exportación o en la creación de la información en excel o en otra parte. Nos hace falta un poco más de información. ¿cuál es la consulta que realizas a la base de datos?

Comment: $llamarBDValidados =  App\Validacion::all();
        $tamanio = $llamarBDValidados->count();

Comment: mira aqui es donde traigo todo el modelo para  hacer el recorrido de ello  para traer el largo de los registros y los registro  y como puedo medir  el cosumo mayor de cada  metodo ?

Answer (score 1):

Tu script es un poco pesado y necesita más tiempo de procesamiento, prueba usando la función `set_time_limit` antes de llamar al código que genera el archivo Excel.

```
set_time_limit(300); // 5 minutos
```

Puedes cambiar el número si tu script necesita más tiempo.

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: gracias una pregunta y como  haria para  alivianar la cunsulta hay algun  metodo o forma  que en vez de enviar   fila por fila lo pueda enviar por lote o fragmentos dentro de un for yo casi no soy experto en for solo se los basico creeria yo el for ,foreach y el doble for  @Vlady

Comment: Quizás si sacas el `$writer->save("reporte.xls");` del for mejore bastante.

Comment: muchas gracias  por ayudarme en este problema ya lo pude resolver  y si @Vlady tenias razon   mejoro muchisimo el borrar el $whiter del for y lo coloque al terminar el for para que guardara todo y funciono